# Logback + Janino + Resin issue with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback, resin, janino

Hi I am using the following version of logback and Janino :

```
  <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-core" rev="1.0.11" conf="runtime"/>
  <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.11" conf="runtime"/>
  <dependency org="org.codehaus.janino" name="janino" rev="2.6.1" conf="runtime"/>
```

and logging config using `<if>` conditon is :

```
<root level="INFO">
    <if condition='property("xxx").contains("dev")'>
      <then>
        <appender-ref ref="dev" />
      </then>
    </if>
</root>
```

The error I see is as follows :

7:38:54,729 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.setImplementedInterfaces([Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.PropertyEvalScriptBuilder.build(PropertyEvalScriptBuilder.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.IfAction.begin(IfAction.java:67)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:276)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:148)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:130)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:157)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:143)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:106)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:56)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)

Any ideas why its throwing this error ?

Answer (score 9):

Should also note they changed their group id from *janino* to *org.codehasu.janino* so you'll need to update more than just the version.

````
```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```
````

Answer (score 4):

The `setImplementedInterfaces(Class[])` method is part of `ClassBodyEvaluator` class in janino 2.6.1. Check your class path to see whether a different version of Janino is lurking somewhere. There is a very high likelihood that your class path contains a different version of Janino.

Comment: Your tip helped, seems there was a wrong version of janino jar . Thanks